# How to override or remove data from Postgres on backup creation

Tags: python, postgresql, odoo, backup

I need to know how to override or remove data from Postgres on backup creation
Same way like what Odoo.Sh doing on backup he archive all Cron Jobs except two

I need to do the same but with data in my choice any idea.

I have searched on Odoo core code but didn't find anything can help.